# How to cover a label list under the multi-label classification context into one-hot encoding with pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, one-hot-encoding, multilabel-classification

I have a list of one batch data with multi-label for every sample. So how to covert it into torch.Tensor in one-hot encoding?
For example, with `batch_size=5` and `class_num=6`,

```py
label =[
[1,2,3],
[4,6],
[1],
[1,4,5],
[4]
]
```

how to make it into one-hot encoding in pytorch?

```py
label_tensor=tensor([
[1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0]
])
```

Answer (score 3):

If the **batch size** can be derived from `len(labels)`:

```py
def to_onehot(labels, n_categories, dtype=torch.float32):
    batch_size = len(labels)
    one_hot_labels = torch.zeros(size=(batch_size, n_categories), dtype=dtype)
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        # Subtract 1 from each LongTensor because your
        # indexing starts at 1 and tensor indexing starts at 0
        label = torch.LongTensor(label) - 1
        one_hot_labels[i] = one_hot_labels[i].scatter_(dim=0, index=label, value=1.)
    return one_hot_labels
```

and you have 6 categories and want the output to be a **tensor of integers**:

```py
to_onehot(labels, n_categories=6, dtype=torch.int64)
```

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

I would stick to `torch.float32` in case you want to use label smoothing, *mix-up* or something along those lines later.

Answer (score 0):

To handle any situation (include string labels) I've extended @karniol's answer:

```py
def multihot_encoder(labels, dtype=torch.float32):
    """ Convert list of label lists into a 2-D multihot Tensor """
    label_set = set()
    for label_list in labels:
        label_set = label_set.union(set(label_list))
    label_set = sorted(label_set)

    multihot_vectors = []
    for label_list in labels:
        multihot_vectors.append([1 if x in label_list else 0 for x in label_set])

    # To keep track of which columns are which, set dtype to None and...
    # import pandas as pd
    if dtype is None:
        return pd.DataFrame(multihot_vectors, columns=label_set)
    return torch.Tensor(multihot_vectors).to(dtype)
```

Your use case:

```py
label_lists = [[1,2,3], [4,6], [1], [1,4,5], [4]]
>>> multihot_encoder(label_lists)
```

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

If you want to keep track of your labels (feature names) before converting your dataset to a Tensor, just set dtype to None:

```py
label_lists = [
    ['happy', 'kind'], ['sad', 'mean'],
    ['loud', 'happy'], ['quiet', 'kind']
    ]
multihot_encoder(label_lists, dtype=None)
```

```
   happy  kind  loud  mean  quiet  sad
0      1     1     0     0      0    0
1      0     0     0     1      0    1
2      1     0     1     0      0    0
3      0     1     0     0      1    0
```

and you have 6 categories and want the output to be a **tensor of integers**:

```py
to_onehot(labels, n_categories=6, dtype=torch.int64)
```

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```